# Can't set icon in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

```
# Imports
from tkinter import *

# Root
root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter")
root.iconbitmap("C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\Tkinter\icon.png")

# Main loop
root.mainloop()
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\Tkinter\app.py", line 9
     root.iconbitmap("C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\Tkinter\icon.png")
                     ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated #\UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Try putting r before C: like `r"C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\Tkinter\icon.png"`.

Comment: File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\Image Viewer\main.py", line 10
    root.iconbitmap(r "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\Image Viewer\icon.png")
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yasa: In that case update your question so it has the new error you are now getting. Note that the `r` should be right next to the `"`. i.e. `r"C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop...`

Comment: I also think the icon file maye have to be of type `.ico`, not `.png` (at least on Windows).

Comment: okay so i basically needed a .ico file and not a png file. Thanks guys