# _tkinter.TclError: error reading bitmap file "logo.ico"

Tags: python, tkinter, bitmap, ico

I keep receiving this error message. I googled a lot but the results didn't help. I checked the location of the file plenty of times.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('580x330')
root.configure(background='#FFFFFF')
root.title('title')
root.iconbitmap('@logo.ico')
```

Comment: Please check you spelling and remove all swearing.

Comment: Fixed your question. Next time I will have to report you. If you ask nicely people are more willing to help you.

Comment: Have you tried using the fill file path like: `root.iconbitmap("C:/.../.../.../logo.ico")`? Also please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing)

Comment: Ty, tried it but: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299073/cant-set-icon-in-tkinter?noredirect=1&lq=1). If that doesn't help please edit your question to also include the ico.

Comment: Use `r'...path'`.

Comment: Did you try removing the `@` character like `root.iconbitmap('logo.ico')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('580x330')
root.configure(background='#FFFFFF')
root.title('title')
# Make sure that it is the full path to your .ico file
root.iconbitmap(r"C:\...\...\...\logo.ico")
```